# Access great-grantparent elements in a generic way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML structure with several divs, something like this:

```
<div class="radio-button-category">
     <input type="hidden" class="appointment" name="salutation" id="salutation">
     <div class="radio-button-wrapper">
          <div class="mod_6">
              <div class="radio-button-wrapper">
                   <span class="radio-button" data-value="M" data-input="#salutation"></span>
                   <span>Sr.</span>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mod_6">
              <div class="radio-button-wrapper">
                  <span class="radio-button" data-value="F" data-input="#salutation"></span>
                  <span>Sra.</span>
              </div>
          </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So now, I want to access the  tag from the  to change its value when clicked, and I need a more elegant solution than this:

```
 $('span.radio-button').parent().parent().parent().siblings('input').val($(this).data('value'));
```

I have tried with find(), closest()... but nothing works. Thank you :)

Comment: What does `this` refers to? and as you have specified id why not simple `$('#salutation').val($(this).data('value'))`

Comment: this is the span you are refering to in the first place

Comment: You've set an `id` on the `input`, so you don't need any DOM traversal as these have to be unique. Just use `$('#salutation').val($(this).data('value'))` as @Satpal mentioned. If you have multiple elements with the same id then that's another issue which needs to be addressed

Comment: Yes, but I would like to re-use this line, and instead of using the id use a class or something more generic

Comment: have u tried **.parents("[classname]")** ?

Comment: Yes, and it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click','.radio-button',function(){ 
   var inp_data = $(this).parents().siblings('input').data("value");  
   //var inp_data = $(this).data("value");  // if you want M to F values
     console.log(inp_data);
     
     
     
});
```

```css
 .radio-button {
    padding: 5px; 
    border: none;
  border-radius:100%;
    background: red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-button-category">
     <input type="hidden" class="appointment" data-value="your value" name="salutation" id="salutation">
     <div class="radio-button-wrapper">
          <div class="mod_6">
              <div class="radio-button-wrapper">
                   <span class="radio-button" data-value="M" data-input="#salutation"></span>
                   <span>Sr.</span>
             </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="mod_6">
              <div class="radio-button-wrapper"> 
                  <span class="radio-button" data-value="F" data-input="#salutation"></span>
                  <span>Sra.</span>
              </div>
          </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is eq(4)??

Comment: Actually, we did not need 4. (sory)

Comment: This is not working. I don't want to access it, I want to change its value everytime a span is clicked